# Is there a point in passing arguments(variables) to a function which can already access them from its closure?

Tags: javascript, function

For example:

```
let a = 5;
let b = 6;

function sum1() {
    console.log(a + b);
}

function sum2(a, b) {
    console.log(a + b);
}
```

Are there any cases where one of the examples won't work?

Comment: `sum2` is a pure function while `sum1` isn't. It is much easier to reason about and test `sum2`, since it is not dependent on any *external* state. `sum1` may return a different result each time it is called while `sum2` will always return the same result given that the parameters are the same.

Comment: While `sum2(a, b)` is the same as `sum1()`, other possible calls like `sum(1, 2)` are not.

Comment: by naming the arguments to sum2 the same as the outer variables `a` and `b`  you've really muddied the _intent_ of what you're trying to accomplish.  Please be clear about what you intend for it to be doing - that's the only way we can say whether it "works".

Comment: "*Are there any cases where one of the examples won't work?*" well, `sum1` is not reusable, for a start. You can use `sum2` elsewhere by passing it around, partially applying it, composing it and otherwise manipulating it to build up more things with it. `sum1` on the other hand is almost useless out of this context, as the caller cannot alter `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 0):

In sum1 as you can’t pass arguments, it will do 5 + 6.
But in sum2 you can do something like this:
sum2(7,8) >> 15
sum2(1,5) >> 6

It’s better sum2, because use call it from anywhere and passing it arguments, you want.